# how to use nested attributes for the ratings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

i have the post controllers

```
def show
  @post = @topic.posts.find(params[:id])
  @rate=@post.ratings.all
  @post.ratings.build
  @rate = Rating.where(post_id: @post.id).group("rate").count
end

private 
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :topic_id, tags_attributes: [:tagname], tag_ids: [], ratings_attribute: [:rate])
end
```

post.rb

```
 class Post < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :ratings,dependent: :destroy
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :ratings
 end
```

rating.rb

```
class Rating < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  validates_presence_of :rate
end
```

show.html

```html
   <div class="container" >
    <h3 class="mt-5"><b><%= @topic.topicname %> Post </b></h3><hr>
     <div class="well">
    <h4><strong>Title : </strong><%= @post.title %></h4><hr>
    <h4><strong>Body : </strong><%= @post.body %></h4>
    </div>
    <%= render 'tags/tags' %>
    <h3>Ratings:</h3>
    <%= form_for [@topic, @post] do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :ratings, @post.ratings.build do |builder| %>
      <fieldset>
        <% for i in 1..5 %>
          <%= builder.radio_button :rate, i %><%= i %>
        <% end %>
      </fieldset>
    <% end %>
    <%=f.submit  %>
   <% end %>
      <% if @rate.present? %>
      <% @rate.each do |k, v| %>
      <% t = k %>
      <% for i in 1..t%>
      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
      <% end %>
      <%t=t+1 %>
      <%= v %><br>
    <% end %>
     <% end %>
  <div class="row" >
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <%= render 'comments/comments' %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <%= render 'comments/form', object: @post %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this project i need to use the ratings as a nested attribute into the post model and using fieldset in the show page of posts i want to give ratings using radio buttons for the post i am viewing. My issue is when I give a rating using radio button the rate value is not inserted into the the database.

Comment: Can you please add log of server ?

Comment: You are overriding the value of `@rate` in `show`

Comment: Do you think it could be the missing 's' in `ratings_attribute(s)` in permitted params?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh excellent :)

Comment: @JagdeepSingh ya i missed s in ratings_attribute(s) now i fixed it

Comment: @JagdeepSingh ya i solved the issue that i posted

Comment: @JagdeepSingh could u please give the rspec tese cases for the post controllers for ratings

Comment: @PraveenR what do you mean? That is a whole different question than this one. Wait. That is not at all a question. SO is not a "do my work for me" site. Please follow the docs, try to write the Rspecs, and if you are stuck, post a new question with appropriate details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, you were missing 's' in the end of `ratings_attribute(s)` in permitted params. Change your method `post_params` to following:

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post)
        .permit(:title, :body, :topic_id,
                tags_attributes: [:tagname],
                tag_ids: [],
                ratings_attributes: [:rate])
end
```